# Python Scraping and reading encrypted return with requests

Tags: python, encryption, web-scraping, python-requests

I am scraping a number of websites for data. Many websites I have no problem scraping at all, but a couple return encrypted data. I have created a basic demo below of what is going on. Is there a way to decrypt the returned results?

```
headers_Get = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
}

q = 'www.nike.com'
s = requests.Session()
url = 'http://' + q 
r = s.get(url, headers=headers_Get)
r.text
```

The above code returns the expected html from Nike.Com.

However, if we run the same code and replace q = 'www.nike.com', with q = 'www.vanityfair.com' we receive code that looks like the following:

```
\x1bX�U?�(J�\x1a��|=;�:���N�\x01��J�.��$�D[����1�\x11[T2/����rq}�\x00ʁ�\x06(��J,�ܳR�\'Gs�я�l�\n���)�Qf��\x11�\x15�\x80��\r\x1d�o �<�o�??>}�������\x07��\n�\x1dE\ti�\x19\x01D�)�z\x06\x00p�\x18�e\n(�s&��\x1c��ga$e\n�PGd\x07琚\x17I�8�ީ�A�\x1f�c^�C�zh�Ǵ�t��@�X��wbl\x18�|}[��o���g\x02;����8+��:6\x039���-\x19\x1b��Q���\t\x1aJJ\x1b�\x11��\rq\x0c\x11��p�Q\x10\x18����\x14͋��\x0bus��e3X�w�狔�\x1d��6�nwen�\x02\x08�J�O�߯ףQ�T\x0c�P����0���]]��bI��5��Em/n��������ze�n.Wx��(\x05���+}���^�.qa����E�V�e���}w}�\x16�U]/�]-�d͋$ਡ�aėup��m���o\x06'
```

Im guessing this is the site upgrading the insecure request, but how can I decrpyt these results to receive the expected html code like Nike?

Note: I get the same results with post and get.

Comment: Try with `r.content` instead of `r.text`.

Comment: r.content does not resolve the issue, it simply replaces the question marks with the associated Unicode abbreviations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the request without the `Accept-Encoding` header, that way the server doesn't compress the message to be sent